# global constant not updating with correct values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 4, I have a config/config.yml that I want to keep separate from config/secrets.yml. I updated the configuration to include twilio info:

```
development:
  sendgrid:
    username: username
    password: password
    domain: domain
  twilio:
    account_sid: account_sid
    auth_token: auth_token
    twilio_number: twilio_number
```

In config/application.rb, I load the global constant (I cannot load it in initializer because I need to make use of it in environments/*rb and environments/*rb are loaded before initializers). Here is the global constant:

```
module RailsDevise
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.before_configuration do
      ::APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]
    end
  end
end
```

When I load the console, the changes are not reflected:

```
> APP_CONFIG
 => {"sendgrid"=>{"username"=>"username", "password"=>"password", "domain"=>"domain"}, "twilio"=>{"account_sid"=>"account_sid", "auth_token"=>"auth_token"}}
```

However, for sure they are there:

```
> YAML.load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml"))
{"development"=>{"sendgrid"=>{"username"=>"username", "password"=>"password", "domain"=>"domain"}, "twilio"=>{"account_sid"=>"account_sid", "auth_token"=>"auth_token", "twilio_number"=>"twilio_number"}}
```

What kind of caching can be going on? I reloaded the console several times, it should be reloading the entire application. But it is not detecting the changes in the yml file.

Comment: Why is it when I close the terminal on the mac and reopen and now it works. I don't understand how the terminal (and perhaps a running ruby process) is linked to this ruby variable.

Comment: is it possible you had something like spring running in the background?

Comment: @JedSchneider I had faye with the sync gem running in the background, but still not sure how that affects this issue.

Comment: So, if you run `spring status` you get nothing at all?

Comment: @smathy right now I get "Spring is not running." But I tried what you said after I quit and reopened the terminal. After reopening the terminal, the variable updated correctly. So obviously some running process was causing the problem. I am not sure what spring is. But I do have a sync process running with: spawn "rackup sync.ru -E production"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sync` wouldn't affect your own `rails console` though, but `spring` would have. `spring` basically runs in the background and keeps your app resident in memory to make (re)starting the `rails console`, or running tests, etc. quicker. It detects file changes and restarts itself, but it can't watch everything and definitely doesn't watch for changes in your own custom YAML config files. Having `spring` running would precisely describe your symptoms, and it's part of the default Gemfile.

When these things happen again: `spring stop` and try again.

Comment: I do have Spring in my Gemfile. Is there a way to check within the console if spring is running? I didn't even realize Spring was there.

Comment: `spring status` as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: good to know my hunch was right! `spring stop` `spring start` works too.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to manually `spring start` - the next time you use anything that uses spring, that will start spring automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rails 5 and I had the same issue, clearing the cache worked.

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```